# Margin between Navigator and ListView in react native android

Tags: android, listview, react-native

I am writing an app in React Native specifically for Android, and I believe there is a some issue with Navigator and List View.
In render(), I render a navigator. In renderscene() of navigator, I return a ListView. The ListView and Navigator are displayed on the Page. 
But, ListView is displayed one layer below the Navigator, due to which Some initial rows of ListView are hidden below the Navigator.

Here is the code -

```js
 render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          navigator={this.props.navigator}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar style={{backgroundColor: '#246dd5', alignItems: 'center'}}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
          } />
    );
  }
  
  
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    
        return (
            <ListView
                 dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                 renderRow={this.renderState.bind(this)}
                 // renderScrollComponent={props => <RecyclerViewBackedScrollView {...props} />}
                 renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} style={styles.separator} />}
                 style={styles.listView}
                 enableEmptySections={true}
            />
        );
  }
```

And, Here is the output -

[image]

Please tell me a solution , so that ListView gets started after Navigation Bar on the same layer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some margin to list view. even i had same issue

Comment: @sush what about those phones that doesn't have navigation bar on screen?

Comment: wt u mean by doesnt have ? even that also u can handle, react native supports the ternary operators.